# HorizontalScrollView with four RelativeLayout, each of which occupies the entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am having a problem creating a `HorizontalScrollView` on Android that will serve as a tutorial.

This ScrollView contains a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, and inside there are 4 RelativeLayout, each of which must fill the screen.

But if I set `layout_width = "match_parent"` on each RelativeLayout, this does not work at all, but it's like it was set to `"wrap_content"`

The `layout_width` of ScrollView is set as `"wrap_content"` and on LinearLayout is set as `"0dp"`, but changing this I did not see any changes.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a ViewPager instead of an horizontal ScrollView to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Sherekan thanks, what is the difference?

Comment: ViewPager is for what you want to achieve ,it can auto scroll page to page.

Comment: A ViewPager works with fragments, where each fragment represents one "screen", so you can create N fragment (one for each screen) and just navigate through them with the functionality the view pager provides. Take in account that if you end up implementing this as an horizontal scroll view, your 4 layouts will be, for example, scrollable without stopping where there's a "screen" change (i don't know if you understand what i'm trying to say, if not i'll try to explain myself better)

Comment: @Sherekan ok thanks i will try with ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your RelativeLayout width is set to `match_parent` of the parent LinearLayout which is`0dp`.

Try giving your LinearLayout some width

**By the way** why do you have to use `HorizontalScrollView`, Use `ViewPager` instead.More about viewpager [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html)

Example

in your **parent_layout.xml**

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

You can find more about the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/ProMobile/ViewPagerTutorial)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I change the width of LinearLayout, nothing else change

Comment: @Ilario What about the `layout_height` ?

Comment: layout_weight is always match_parent.. but there is no problem with height

Comment: @Ilario Why don't you use `ViewPager` instead?

Comment: @Ilario I tried but the code was going to be too long for an answer,but the github project I have added in the edit does the job.Check out the edit again.

Comment: just one question... how you release the ViewPager? thanks

Comment: @Ilario what do you mean by releasing the ViewPager?

Comment: release memory occupied by ViewPager.. how to close ViewPager? simple viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int  size = horizontalScrollView.getChildCount();
int screenW =getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
for(int i = 0 ;i <size ;i++){
     View v = horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(i);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.width = screenW;
    v.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use the scroll view you should use the width of Relative layout in fix dp like 300dp or 200 dp otherwise scroll view take its width as it require like wrap_content

so use like this `layout_width = "200dp"`